# Fable-Elmish - Properly handle forms in F# with SAFE stack

Tags: f#

**Context:** I am using Fable and Elmish in a website that has a login page with two simple inputs: email and password. It works just fine if the button doesn't have the type ***submit***, but by lacking such I cannot press *Return* in the form to send it, I have to go and click on it, which wouldn't happen if the element were a ***submit*** type.

**The problem is:** how do I properly handle forms with the SAFE stack? If I add the ***submit*** type I need an ***action*** in the form to some Route (assuming this would be a dispatch Msg in Elmish), however that makes the browser reload the page with the form as query params and end up stuck in login.

Code example:

```
form [Class !!classes?form (*; Action <- Should I make a dispatch here?*)] [
    formControl [ HTMLAttr.Required true ] [
        textField [
            HTMLAttr.Label "Example"
            HTMLAttr.Type "email"
            OnInput (fun x -> setExample x.Value) (* Simple hook for managing the state changes *)
            MaterialProp.Value example (* Using material UI, but you may disconsider this *)
        ] []
    ]
    button [
             HTMLAttr.Type "submit"
             OnClick (fun _ ->
                dispatch (Authenticate example) (* <- Here is where I dispatch currently *)
             )
    ] [
        str "Enter"
    ]   
]
```

Comment: "submit" buttons submit the form. You just need to `preventDefault` in your click handler before calling the `dispatch`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks, that solves the problem :)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Since it solves the problem it looks like an answer to me, you could post it as such.

Comment: I don't know where to get `preventDefault`. I don't have a project set up on my machine and I couldn't find it in the docs.